# Half step modulations in music

Tags: jazz, classical-music, modulation, enharmonics

I'm looking for cllasical/Jazz music pieces with half step (semitone) modulations.
I'm assuming that this type of modulation could appear in the form of enharmonic modulation- when the pivot chord (Ger+6 for example) will be the V of the new tonic.

Need this for a school assignment and I could really use some help cause I'm kinda lost right now...

Thanks!
Shir

Comment: We don't do homework! That's your job! Sorry, but the site isn't around for this sort of q&a. Please read the Help Centre for guidance. Googling came straight up with several.

Comment: Welcome! To address the pivot chord: There doesn't always have to be a true "pivot," something that's explainable in both keys. Many versions of "Mack the Knife" just jump straight from I to the V of the next half-step up, to the new I.